# how mature is this for generics

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Inside form I'm taking users input from textbox as text to perform search. There is also radio values which filters search. So I can search for a book by title, by tag and by author.

Right now I'm using switch statement to determine which radio value is selected and based on that value I'm calling repository to retrieve data.

```
var checkedSearchBy = panelSearchBy.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);

string searchBy = checkedSearchBy.Text;
case "ByTitle":
   var data = repository.GetDetailsByTitle(txtUsersInput);
   break;
case "ByTag":
   var data = repository.GetDetailsByTag(txtUsersInput);
   break;
case "ByAuthor":
   var data = repository.GetDetailsByAuthor(txtUsersInput);
   break;
```

and on repository side (I'm using dapper orm) I have three methods which almost identical queries.
How can I refactor this code to call one method instead of those three?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One technique for doing this is to define a delegate matching the signature of your 'Get' methods there, and define a fixed Dictionary of type `<string,(DelegateName)>.`

Then you can just do `var data = myDictionary[searchBy](txtUsersInput)`

For example, in the class definition:

```
private delegate void MyDelegate(string input);
private Dictionary<string, MyDelegate> myDictionary;
```

and in the constructor:

```
myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyDelegate> {
  { "ByTitle", repository.GetDetailsByTitle },
  { "ByTag", repository.GetDetailsByTag }
  /*etc*/
};
```

Comment: can you provide more details please. If I understand correctly I would remove switch statement and keep existing three methods?

Comment: Now I think about it, I'm not entirely sure this solves your problem, as you do still need the three methods. To know how to refactor those three methods in one, you probably need to show us those methods, or at least what varies between then.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example:

```
var list = new[] { "Hello", "World", "Example" };

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<string>>>();

dictionary.Add("alphabet", a => a.OrderBy(b => b));
dictionary.Add("length", a => a.OrderBy(b => b.Length));

var result = dictionary["alphabet"](list);
```

Returns

```
Example
Hello
World
```